# Stroke выходит за границы холста SVG

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg

При использовании `stroke` svg выходит за рамки viewbox. Как это исправить?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 441 394.36">
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="35" d="M329.9,1.5c60.56,0,109.6,49.03,109.6,109.47c0,109.47-109.6,171.8-219.06,281.27C110.97,282.77,1.5,220.44,1.5,110.97C1.5,50.53,50.54,1.5,110.97,1.5c54.73,0,82.1,27.37,109.47,82.1 C247.8,28.87,275.17,1.5,329.9,1.5z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: stroke-width + viewBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень часто бывают случаи, что невозможно методом "тыка" поймать нужные параметры `viewBox`

В этом случае выручит метод JS `getBBox()`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 441 394.36" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <path id="p1" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="35"  d="M329.9,1.5c60.56,0,109.6,49.03,109.6,109.47c0,109.47-109.6,171.8-219.06,281.27C110.97,282.77,1.5,220.44,1.5,110.97C1.5,50.53,50.54,1.5,110.97,1.5c54.73,0,82.1,27.37,109.47,82.1 C247.8,28.87,275.17,1.5,329.9,1.5z" />
</svg> 
<script>
console.log(p1.getBBox());
</script>
```

Подставляем получившиеся значения во `viewBox`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="1.5 1.5 438 390.74" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <path id="p1" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  d="M329.9,1.5c60.56,0,109.6,49.03,109.6,109.47c0,109.47-109.6,171.8-219.06,281.27C110.97,282.77,1.5,220.44,1.5,110.97C1.5,50.53,50.54,1.5,110.97,1.5c54.73,0,82.1,27.37,109.47,82.1 C247.8,28.87,275.17,1.5,329.9,1.5z" />
</svg> 
<script>
console.log(p1.getBBox());
</script>
```

Но `getBBox()`выводит параметры прямоугольника, описывающего фигуру svg без учета `stroke-wifth` А она у нас `34`

Второй момент,- при широкой строке, внешняя часть (половина строки) уйдет за пределы холста SVG (красная рамка) поэтому это надо учесть и изменить соответственно параметры `viewBox`

Было по расчетам `getBBox()` `viewBox="1.5 1.5 438 390.74"` Прибавляем `34` (по половине  строки с каждой стороны)

**Стало**

`viewBox="-15.5 -15.5 472 424.74`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="-15.5 -15.5 472 422.74" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <path id="p1" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="34"  d="M329.9,1.5c60.56,0,109.6,49.03,109.6,109.47c0,109.47-109.6,171.8-219.06,281.27C110.97,282.77,1.5,220.44,1.5,110.97C1.5,50.53,50.54,1.5,110.97,1.5c54.73,0,82.1,27.37,109.47,82.1 C247.8,28.87,275.17,1.5,329.9,1.5z" />
</svg> 
<script>
console.log(p1.getBBox());
</script>
```

Comment: Совсем забыл про этот метод

Comment: @Sevastopol' Да, всё верно Это наиболее частые вопросы: почему, обрезается фигура, почему svg не на месте или вообще не виден и всё это великий и ужасный viewBox/ В этом примере хоть не было масштабирования

Comment: @Voprositel старайтесь делать отступы от краев SVG документа, если конечно рисуете сами. И тогда не будет таких сюрпризов.

Answer (score 3):

Я так полагаю, нужно `viewBox="-16 -16 474 433"` ?

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-16 -16 474 433">
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="35" d="M329.9,1.5c60.56,0,109.6,49.03,109.6,109.47c0,109.47-109.6,171.8-219.06,281.27C110.97,282.77,1.5,220.44,1.5,110.97C1.5,50.53,50.54,1.5,110.97,1.5c54.73,0,82.1,27.37,109.47,82.1 C247.8,28.87,275.17,1.5,329.9,1.5z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Блин.. Точно, можно же было отрицательный `viewbox` использовать, а я изображение двигал и уменьшал :D (с меня +)